# gnuplot - line 0: unexpected or unrecognized token

Tags: gnuplot

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# download death data
wget -O Deaths.txt http://www.randomservices.org/random/data/Deaths.txt
wget -O Pumps.txt http://www.randomservices.org/random/data/Pumps.txt
# Delete the first line
sed 1d Deaths.txt > tempfile1
sed 1d Pumps.txt > tempfile2
# mv tempfile1 Deaths.txt
# mv tempfile2 Pumps.txt
gnuplot -persist -e "set terminal canvas;set xlabel 'x' font 'sans,15';
set ylabel 'y' font ',15';
set title 'Relationship between Deaths and Pumps' font 'sans, 20';
show title;
set label "Most of the deaths is near the pump located in 12.6,11.7" at 16,16;
show label;
set output 'death_pump_relation.html';
plot 'Pumps.txt' with points pt 7 ,'Deaths.txt' with dots;"
```

There is a error: `line 0: unexpected or unrecognized token`

and I cannot get any output

But in fact, there is no line0 in my script

What is wrong with that?

Version : gnuplot V5.2

System: MacOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the working script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# download death data
wget -O Deaths.txt http://www.randomservices.org/random/data/Deaths.txt
wget -O Pumps.txt http://www.randomservices.org/random/data/Pumps.txt
# Delete the first line
sed 1d Deaths.txt > tempfile1
sed 1d Pumps.txt > tempfile2
mv tempfile1 Deaths.txt
mv tempfile2 Pumps.txt
gnuplot -persist -e "set terminal canvas;set xlabel 'x' font 'sans,15';
set ylabel 'y' font ',15';
set title 'Relationship between Deaths and Pumps' font 'sans, 20';
show title;
set label 'Most of the deaths is near the pump located in 12.6,11.7' at 16,16;
show label;
set output 'death_pump_relation.html';
plot 'Pumps.txt' with points pt 7 ,'Deaths.txt' with dots;"
```

output is in death_pump_relation.html

Comment: the " should be there because it shoule match the " after ```gnuplot -persist -e```

Comment: You are correct. The issue is set label "Most of the deaths is near the pump located in 12.6,11.7" at 16,16;   change the " to '

Comment: @al76 for the benefit of future readers, it would be helpful imho if you included that information (i.e. that the issue is the attempt to "nest" quoted strings) in your answer

Answer (score 1):

I know what is wrong there

```
# mv tempfile1 Deaths.txt
# mv tempfile2 Pumps.txt
```

shoule not be commeted